# Develop $f(z) = (1- \frac{1}{z} )^3$ to Laurent's series around $z_{0} = i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Develop $f(z) = (1- \frac{1}{z} )^3$ to Laurent's series around $z_{0} = i$.

I was thinking to cube it first and than observe each member of that sum of four elements and find Laurent's series for it. Is that good thinking?

Comment: That function is analytic on $\;\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\;$ thus that Laurent series will have only positive powers of $\;z-i\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio can you please explain what does that mean for developing it? I'm begginer in this so everything is new to me

Comment: In the title, you wrote that $z_0=1$, but in the body you wrote that $z_0=i$. Which one is correct?

Comment: @user Read my answer below. Try to make sense of all the steps.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the one in body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do Taylor around $\;z_0=i\;$ :

$$\begin{cases}f(i)=\left(1-\frac1i\right)^3=(1+i)^3=2i(1+i)=-2+2i\\
f'(z)=\frac1{z^2}\implies f'(i)=\frac1{i^2}=-1\\
f''(z)=\frac{-2}{z^3}\implies f''(i)=-\frac2{i^3}=-2i\\
f'''(z)=\frac6{z^4}\implies f'''(i)=6\\
\ldots\\
f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\,n!}{z^{n+1}}\implies f^{(n)}(i)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{i^{n+1}}\\
\ldots\end{cases}$$

Thus, the series you're looking for is

$$-2(1-i)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{i^{n+1}}(z-i)^n$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful :)